# Extra < br > at head area of twenty seventeen theme

Tags: html, css

I am using twenty-seventeen theme and have an unusual white space when I insert a `< head >`.  Have checked out wordpress.org support and no answer solved my issue and have googled extensively on this issue already.

If I remove the `< head >< /head >` it goes away but the head only has a title, so why does it have all the `< br >s` (see second image) and resulting white space?  I just want to remove the white space, or at least reduce it, and here is what I have tried so far:

```
.site-content .entry-content {display: none;}

.site-content .entry-header {display: none;}

.site-content .entry-title {display: none;}
```

but none of these solve the issue.

Here is my HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
    <head>
         <title class= "title-class">Single Column Template</title>
    </head>
   <body> 
    <header>Interested in our website and technology reviews? Want further? 
    Submit the form below.</header>
     <main>
             omitted as irrelevant info
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Here is just the Head bit wtih the br's that I never put in my self.  Not sure what is going on.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're breaking something structurally here. Where is this code going? Is this being inserted into a template? What to you get if you View Source, as opposed to using dev tools? It looks like a `<head>` section is being inserted in the `<body>`

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks Jon.  Fixed.  I removed the head tags.  I am showing my lack of understanding on the best way to implement the head section in wordpress.  Appreciate the comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding my comment into an answer...

The problem is you are inserting a complete HTML document into a Wordpress template.

Unless are modifying the outermost "layer" of the template, the doctype, head and body sections of the HTML document already exist. Anything you add will end up somewhere in the `body` tag.

Each HTML document can only have one `<head>` tag, adding more is going to result in erratic browser behavior.

You should be using a combination of `<section>` (optionally), `<header>` and `<h1> - <h6>` tags for header sections.

In Wordpress the title, found in the head, is normally populated from information you supply when adding a page through the Wordpress user interface.

Comment: Thanks Jon, that is exactly what the issue was.  Resolved and webpages white space gone.

Answer (score 0):

If this is occuring and its not in your HTML, im assuming its being added by wordpress. The only thing I can think of is to try to use JQuery/DOM manipulation to hide the br elements as follows:

```
$('.entry-content').find(p > br).hide()
```

Comment: No it should only hide br elements found in the '.entry-content' class that are children of a paragraph

Comment: Thanks Danny, where do I add it as not touched JQuery before?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp should help get you started. You need to copy the CDN as a script in your <head>. Also its important that you only execute the code to hide <br>'s once the elements are loaded using the $( document ).ready() function (https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: fortunately I did not have to do any JQuery as Jon in the other answer picked up my issue and the solution worked.